# How to locate/update Playwright's Chrome registry policies

Tags: windows, registry, chromium, playwright

The Registry path of the PC Chrome-Policies is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome`

But Playwright has its own browsers, so what is the path for Playwright Chrome browsers?

I've searched the Registry for "playwright" and couldn't find anything useful.

In-addition I checked, and the PC browser and Playwright's do not share those policies.